# How the array work in c?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

This is a simple code. But I don't understand this. In this code I would like to enter ten numbers by user and reports if any of them match. First enter 10 numbers that assign in `i[j]`. But variable match carry only 1 number.How could carry 10 numbers. Then if I enter first number 10 then `i[j]` would be first 10.How could third for loop run if enter 10 first.Because `10+1=11`, that greater than 10.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int i[10], j, k, match;

printf("Enter 10 numbers:\n");
for(j=0; j<10; j++) scanf("%d", &i[j]);

for(j=0; j<10; j++){
    match = i[j];

    for(k=j+1; k<10; k++)
        if(match == i[k])
        printf("%d is duplicated\n", match);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: draw the action of the for loop on a piece of paper. Go through each iteration carefully to track what is happening in the program. It shouldn't take you long to understand this basic program.

Comment: and that is why, a debugger (for stepping trough the stages) is the best friend. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note, the third `for` loop is nested inside the second loop. So, for each value of `j` in the other loop body like 0, 1, 2, the inner loop will execute for each time.

If you're bothered that after the first loop, `j` will be `10`, then don't worry, the *statement-1* in the second `for` loop (`for(j=0;...` part) will re-assign the value to `0`, so the second loop will start with a value of `0` for `j`.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Sourav it's really helping me.